# How to fit image into a box of all aspect ratio?

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm dealing with the template png which has a boxed place where I need to fit any size image within that box. How can fit all dimension image to fit in that box in flutter?. I have attached the image.

[image]

I need to add image in that black area which is PNG image and what I tried to implement is here.

```
body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.5,
            right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
            child: imagePicked == null
                ? SizedBox()
                : AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: Image.file(imagePicked, fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
          ),
          const Positioned.fill(
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/notice.png')))),
        ],
      ),
```

But Here I couldn't manage all dimension images. Please help me sort to fit any dimension image into that black box which is also a template image.

Comment: did you try with `Boxfit.fill`?

Comment: Yeah I tried it, Still it' the image is not fitted into that box

Comment: is `notice.png` is for background?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yeah!

Comment: put it as 1st child of `Stack`

Comment: try positioning top:0,left:0,right:0,bottom:0

Comment: @YeasinSheikh It worked! and I also added scale in my code by removing it works now! thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is here overlaying with stack's widgets.
Widget render prioritize bottom to top level on Stack.

In your code-snippet, place-holder is the bottom widget, and it is being prioritized over the selected image.

That's why putting place-holder as 1st widget on stack solve the issue.

Comment: but, if the image is a square i.e., 1:1 the image seems like to be squeeze from top and bottom. Is there any way to solve this

Comment: I will suggest using `SizedBox` as parent of  `Stack` , simply using `Align`/ `Positioned`  as  `Stack` children.

Comment: Can I know the reason for doing so?

Comment: Another solution will be using `Container` with border instead of `Stack` .

Comment: `Stack` require a size  that comes from parent. If you handle stack size, handling children will be easy.

Comment: Hey buddy, Could you help me out with this question? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70076540/how-to-add-curvature-to-a-card-in-flutter)