# How to add curvature to a card in flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So, I'm trying to develop a photobook app which shows the photos in front and back, Now I used card to flip but I need a animation to make it look natural like having a curvature for the card during the flip and the flip should be like turning a stiffened page.

This is what I have tried

```
Widget __transitionBuilder(Widget widget, Animation<double> animation) {
  final rotateAnim = Tween(begin: pi, end: 0.0).animate(animation);
  return AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: rotateAnim,
    child: widget,
    builder: (context, widget) {
      final isUnder = (ValueKey(_showFrontSide) != widget.key);
      var tilt = ((animation.value - 0.5).abs() - 0.5) * 0.003;
      tilt *= isUnder ? -1.0 : 1.0;
      final value = isUnder ? min(rotateAnim.value, pi / 2) : rotateAnim.value;
      return Transform(
        transform: Matrix4.rotationY(value)..setEntry(3, 0, tilt),
        child: widget,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

But it produces the result as follows. Here the card depth is felt but need curvature at the center is it possible to do so?

The result I need is like this image
[image]

The curvature at the center is it possible without curvature?

[image]

Comment: try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_card) package

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Could it make curvature at the center as like as asked?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "curvature at the center"?

Comment: @pskink like turning a page.. Which is like the user holds to the end of the page and the center of the page becomes curvy and that's what I'm asking

Comment: @pskink Please see the image in this link it's bent on center. [here](https://www.prestophoto.com/storage/static/landing/photo-books/open-photo-book.png)

Comment: oh, man, mission impossible - ok it is possible but does not pay off ;-) really too much effort / hassle

Comment: @pskink could you guide me to do so? what are the things I should do? Really man I need your help

Comment: @pskink Really bro need your help please!

Comment: check how similar is made on [android](https://techiemanoj.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/3d-page-curl-animation-on-android/) and then you can do similar thing using `Canvas.drawVertices` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239475/discussion-between-swamper-and-pskink).